# Від чого буває тирса

Tags: вживання-слів

Натрапила на статтю ["Тирса від мільярдів"](http://nikcenter.org/newsItem/42777), у якій ідеться про використання коштів, виділених на відновлення донбаських шкіл. Ключові думки:

> Мільярд сто мільйонів гривень одразу виділили на ремонт тридцяти шкіл. Навіть на ті, які великого ремонту не потребували. Мільярд гривень так поспішали засвоїти, що зробили неякісні проекти... і паралізували роботу шкіл.
>
> Виконавці робіт кажуть — усі роботі робили за технічним регламентом. Утім, батьки і вчителі упевнені — порушення технології були, усе бачили на власні очі.
>
> За результатами цього так званого ремонту Краматорська прокуратура навіть почала кримінальне провадження. Але гроші давав міжнародна ораганізація, Північна екологічна фінансова корпорація NEFCO, яка до виконавців претензій не має. Виходить і постраждалої сторони немає.
> Так відбудова Донецької області стає не просто дорогим задоволенням, а дедалі більше нагадує чорну діру, яка поглинає будь-які суми, що туди потрапляють.

Зацікавила назва, та у самій статті жодного пояснення не надано. За СУМ, слово тирса має 2 значення:

> ТИРСА 1, и, жін. Дрібні частинки деревини, що осипаються під час різання її пилкою.
> ТИРСА 2, и, жін. (Stipa capillata, L.). Трав'яниста степова рослина родини злакових з вузьким листям і квітками, зібраними в пухнасту волоть; ковила волосиста.

У фразеологічному словнику знайшла лише вираз "тирса сиплеться" на означення когось дуже літнього.

То як же розуміти образну назву статті?

Comment: @Yola, то мені мінус за ваш брак часу?

Comment: @Yola, додала у текст запитання загальні висновки, наведені у статті.

Answer (score 5):

Тирса -  це те, що залишається після пиляння чогось. Відповідно, у назві статті йдеться про залишки *попиляних** мільярдів.

---

* - від рос. "распил" - розкрадання коштів.

Comment: А може, замість ремонту отримали тирсу, яка не є будівельним матеріалом.

Comment: @OksanaÇeliker, може й так. Але чисто інтуїтивно/суб'єктивно мені версія Kreiri видається доволі правдоподібною. Тому що це розмовне значення російського слова «распил» (третє [тут](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=распил), третє [тут](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/распил) і стаття [тут](http://lurkmore.to/Распил_и_откат)) доволі відоме.